# Bootstrap col-xs wrapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was testing out the `col-xs` to prevent stacking on smaller devices stated as follows:

> Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the
>   extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-*
>   .col-md-* to your columns.

So I did the following:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And got the following:

[image]

[image]

Any reason why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Might be word wrapping not happening. Try replace the text content with `.` (dot)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. You don't want the cols to stack, and `col-xs-*` isn't stacking...

Comment: I don't want the `xs` columns to stack. I want 12 in one row

Comment: tried the dot, got same result

Comment: Gotcha. My guess is it's the padding on each `col-xs-1`. `width:8.3333333% * 12` will come out to the 100%, but the padding will push it over the top.

Comment: try to set `word-wrap: break-word;` to cells, or `overflow: hidden` or make font-size less

Comment: So I would have to reduce the padding of the first and last column?

Comment: It's something that should work, through I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're after. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/qy8ys5eg/1/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap 3 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10513

The columns can't shrink less that 30px (due to padding) so they eventually they wrap. Showing content in the grid columns < 30px isn't common, so you may not want to use the grid in this case, and instead use an inline list or flexbox.