# Bootstrap grid breaks in smallest size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Using this code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>

    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
      text
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

If you resize the window to the smallest size, the grid breaks.

Here is the **[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/hu9iqlqV8q)** link.

Just open the preview and resize your window to the smallest size, and the grid will break.

3 columns must stay in the same row, but in the smallest size, the last column shifts to the bottom row.

This happens in both versions (**4 & 3.7 (col-xs-2)**)

how can this be fixed?

Comment: <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Email</label>.   Try this

Comment: @pyrogrammer mate! This is not the answer! You want me to make label column 'col-4' for what? What will be fixed with this? Have you even read my question? have you even tested your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The columns can't shrink in width less than 30px (due to padding) so, as screen width narrows, eventually the columns wrap (stack vertically). To prevent this, adjust the padding on the columns inside the `row`. **Bootstrap 4** has a [**`no-gutters`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters) class for this purpose...

https://codeply.com/go/XaBsD5AhJG

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 pl-1">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4 also has [**padding utility classes**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) classes that can be used to adjust padding on individual elements. For example, I used `pl-1`(padding-left) on the last column to give a little space between the input and "text". Another Bootstrap 4 option is to use **`flex-nowrap`** on the `row` which will prevent wrapping and creating horizontal scrolling when there is overflow.

In **Bootstrap 3**, you need to add CSS to adjust the padding.

```
.no-gutters {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.no-gutters>[class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

---

**Related**

[Bootstrap col-xs wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474356/bootstrap-col-xs-wrapping)
[Bootstrap xs columns wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806334/bootstrap-xs-columns-wrap)

Answer (score -1):

You have wronged close the `<div>` tag

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      text
    </div>
    
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: No mate, <div> tag is fine! There is no problem with div closing. I will update my answer to make this more obvious.