# boostrap 4 row breaks

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4, row, col

I dont understand why the row breaks on small devices.
Its inside a row and it has a sum of 12 cols

Running code example here: https://www.bootply.com/Q21DfU6QES.
Please select Mobile View and make it small 
e.g.

[image]

Code

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:red;">
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color: #0F0">
    IMAGE
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #0D0">
    Account info
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #0B0">
    Account Name
  </div>
  <div class="col-3" style="background-color: #090">
    IsValid or not
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not beeing able to find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714749/bootstrap-grid-breaks-in-smallest-size. (flex-nowrap) on row fixed it for me

Comment: use can use  col-xs col-sm- col-lg instead of col-1 col-4 col-4 col-3 for solution.